# How to run maven web application in eclipse using tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

While i'm running maven web application in eclipse neon using tomcat server that throws an error like the followings,Help me to resolve this.

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Answer (score 0):

You should require at least jsp 2.1 and add the required dependencies in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: What is the java version you are using, Check in the eclipse build path that jdk configured correctly also check the compiler. if you are using tomcat 7 or 8 then just downgrade java to 7 and try it.